# Using drag and drop , how to make a moved image visible during transformaton?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

I wrote a simple code using vs.net (with c# language) which allows the user to drag & drop an image
from source to specific destination  ,  my question is , Can I make the image visible during the transformation ? I mean how can I allow the user to see what they are moving during drag and drop ?
I hope my question is clear enough ! 
thanx a lot .

Comment: Unclear what class library you use.  In general, implement the GiveFeedback event.  Set the e.UseDefaultCursors property to false and change the cursor.  Don't go overboard, it becomes hard to drop.

Comment: I've wondered this same question for Winforms Drag & Drop.  Windows Explorer does this when you drag and drop files.  It doesn't seem to actually modify the cursor (or maybe it's incorporating the current cursor in a new cursor), but it's able to draw a semi-transparent image preview even on top of multiple forms (ControlPaint style drawing).  Is this something only Windows can do?

Comment: Hans Passant,
 thanx a lot !I try what you said and it finally works with me !